# What is this insect eating my rose bush?

Tags: insects, roses

The leaves on our rose bush have been nibbled at. Today I found this creature hanging upside down under the leaves. What is it and how do I prevent them from eating my plants?

[image]

**Edit**:
The rose is planted in the ground since one year. It was planted with special soil for rozes that contains fertilizer. I don't know when that will "run out" and further fertilizer is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This critter is not your problem.  Interesting critter...your roses need a balanced fertilizer.  Looks like a major phosphorus deficiency but can't be sure.  When did you last fertilize and what and how much did you use?

This COULD be spider mite and that critter is gobbling them up.  Please take a picture of the underside of the leaf.  Get a magnifying glass.  Are there any indications of very fine webbing?

Is this in a pot or is this rose in the garden?  Send a picture of its environment, please.

Comment: I'm on holiday so can't provide photos of the environment, but I edited my question to include information on the environment of this plant.

Comment: If you haven't fertilized for a year your plant needs some fertilizer!  Are you traveling a lot?  I recommend this Ortho's Osmocote.  The only product I will use made by Ortho.  Fairly common as well.  Extended release and doesn't need to be applied but 2 or 3 times per year.  Usually two for out door plants.  Gosh, what were 'holiday' or vacations like?  I live in one long extended holiday I guess.  Hope you are making good use of this time.  Did you bury your phone?

Comment: I did bury my phone after reading your comment/advice :-) Thank you for the advice. I will fertilize the plant.

Comment: Very very cool Akhil!!  You are on vacation and that phone is a very bad enemy!!